# Deferred functions and making sure final function receives both data

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I would like for the function displayResults() to get the data before it renders the value. The functions getResultA() and getResultB() are using $.Deferred. The function getResultB() is dependent on the results from getResultA().

```
function getResultA() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  .
  .
  .
  .
  deferred.resolve(someValue);
  return deferred.promise();
}

function getResultB() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  .
  .
  getResultA().done(function(someValue) {
    deferred.resolve(someValue);
    return deferred.promise();
  })
}

function displayResults() {
  getResultB().done(function(response) {
    // display the response
  })
}
```

Is my code correct?

Comment: *"Is my code correct?"* does it work? that's probably be a pretty strong indicator of it not being correct, if it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getResultB()` is a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).  You already have a promise returned from `getResultA()`.  You don't need to create a new one.  You can just return the one you already have.

```
function getResultB() {
  .
  .
  return getResultA().then(function(someValue) {
      // whatever code you want here
      // code here can return a new value, return the value you already have
      // after doing some other operations or can return a new promise that
      // will be added to the chain
      return someValue;
  });
}
```

You can then use `getResultB()` just how you were planning:

```
function displayResults() {
  getResultB().then(function(response) {
    // display the response
  })
}
```

Note: I switched to use `.then()` instead of `.done()` because that is the ES6 standards way of coding with promises (and it works with jQuery too).  So, as jQuery moves to be more consistent with the promise standards or as you code with promises from sources other than jQuery, you won't have to change your code or your style.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaning it jfriend00! That helps a lot!